# Oracle SQL Query to find the existence of characters in string

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle database and trying to find out the query which should return the result when there is a special character(',`,(,)) exist on the string.

I am trying something like this,

```
select username from users where username like (',`,~,(,));
```

I tried to achieve the same using the below query,

```
select username from users where (username like '%`%' OR username like '%~%');
```

It doesn't consider the second condition and returns the value to the first condition only.

Is there any function/methods using which this result can be fetched?

Comment: which database are you using Oracle?

Comment: I am using Timesten database

Comment: The second query should get you all users whose names contain `\`` or `~` or both. Are you sure it doesn't? Or am I misunderstanding "It doesn't consider the second condition"?

Comment: Please confirm the list of special characters you need to check.Is it single-quote, comma, backtick, round brackets and tilde? If so the regexp is `'['',\`()~]'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions and check all special characters with one condition:

```
SELECT username 
FROM users 
WHERE regexp_instr(username,'[''`\(\)]') > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school style without regexp

```
where length(translate(username, '_''`~()', '_')) <> length(username)
```